For std::stringstream ss<< static_cast<int>(data[0]) + ".dat"; which methods is invoked for '+'?
Why can this code be complied and run?
The intended expression is:
ss<<"0x" << std::hex << "B_CS2_0x" << static_cast<int>(data[0])  + ".dat";

But I am really curious that why it compiles and could run?
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main()
{
  unsigned char data[5]={0x25};
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss<<"0x" << std::hex << "B_CS2_0x" << static_cast<int>(data[0])  + ".dat";

  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}


<< has lower precedence than +. So you can shorten your example to an [mre] by asking why static_cast<int>(data[0])  + ".dat" works.

Presumably your "intended expression" uses << instead of +? Right now you have the exact same expression.

Array decays to pointer eagerly. Pointer and integer can be added and result is pointer.

@John There is used the built-in operator + with a pointer and an integer. That is there is used the pointer arithmetic.

Does this answer your question? C++ Can't use vector and string literal in cout

@Botje Yes, I intend to use << instead of +?  "Right now you have the exact same expression", I can't get it.

Your question text has the exact same expression in the two sentences.

If k is an integer, k + ".dat" is the same as ".dat" + k, which is the same as &".dat"[0] + k, which is the same as &".dat"[k].

Just use C++20 std::format: auto s = std::format("0xB_CS2_0x{:x}.dat", +data[0]);.

or just replace + with a <<. https://godbolt.org/z/9hc4KTqsT

Try and run the code as well.
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main()
{
  unsigned char data[5]={0x25};
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss <<"0x" << std::hex << "B_CS2_0x" ;
  auto a = static_cast<int>(data[0])  + ".dat";
  ss << a - 37;
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

I converted your code to see what is the assembly for +.
About assembly, It is really hard  to explain fully without any doubt. You can try to do it with overloaded + op and try to detect the diff.
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-69]   // LOAD data[0]
        movzx   eax, al                  // This is to just make sure 0 alignment
        add     rax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2    // the address of the string ".dat" to added to the current value rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax  // Calculated value stored in a

As you can see it is build in + operation between pointer and int.
More specifically a is const char *

1.It's a little hard for me to understand the assembly. Could please add some comment?
2.How you acquire the assembly?
3.How to find the corresponding assembly for  auto a = static_cast<int>(data[0])  + ".dat"?

For very simple thing like this I use Compiler Explorer. Otherwise you dump the object code. g++ -S -o filename.s filename.cpp can be used to produce assembly code as well.
